# How do I get the Canvas element to fill the entire center part of a BorderPane?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, layout, fxml

I am trying to create a simple app that will have a menu bar at the top of a BorderPane (this works) and a Canvas that takes up the rest of the space. I'm using the BorderPane since it seems to best match what I am trying to do. Currently, the Canvas element is always 0 pixels wide and that is obviously not what I want.

I have tried binding the size of the canvas to the BorderPane, putting the Canvas inside VBox/HBox groups, putting it in a AnchorPane, setting the margin.

```xml
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:id="border"
            fx:controller="BoardMenuController"
            prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
    <top>
        <MenuBar>
            <menus>
                <Menu text="File">
                    <MenuItem text="New"/>
                    <MenuItem text="Open"/>
                    <MenuItem text="Save"/>
                    <MenuItem text="Save As"/>
                    <SeparatorMenuItem/>
                    <MenuItem text="Exit" onAction="#onExitClicked"/>
                </Menu>
                <Menu text="Edit">
                    <MenuItem text="Hint"/>
                    <MenuItem text="Shuffle"/>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
    </top>
    <center>
        <Canvas fx:id="canvas"/>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

So that FXML file should work but only the menu is being displayed correctly.

Comment: It should already fill the center area.  How can you tell it’s zero pixels wide?

Comment: @VGR I'm using System.out.println(canvas.getWidth()) to tell how wide it is.

Comment: And where did you place that System.out.println statement?  You need to wait for the Scene to lay out its contents before examining the size of the Canvas.

Comment: I put it in the initialize method of the controller. When I manually add a width and a height in the FXML (changing it to <Canvas fx:id="canvas" width=300 height=300/>), I can see it just fine.

Comment: try to bind the canvas width and height to its container

Comment: @AhmedEmad I did try to bind it to the BorderPane with canvas.widthProperty().bind(border.widthProperty()) and the same for height. Still did not work.

Comment: A `Canvas` is [not resizable](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#isResizable()) (in the context of layout), you have to explicitly give it the appropriate dimensions. Note that making a `Canvas` smaller will remove all drawings outside the now-smaller bounds and they won't reappear if you make the `Canvas` bigger again. In other words, a dynamically sized `Canvas` has the potential to repeatedly lose information.